# Issue with MVC Core routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have an MVC core site with the default route set up:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

which creates rule {controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}

I have a link that is generated using a tag helper like so.

```
 <a asp-controller="Help" asp-action="privacy-policy" asp-route-id="@Model.id" target="_blank">
        privacy policy
    </a>
```

This generates the following link:

```
http://localhost:63110/help/privacy-policy/9b933739-15d0-4c60-a84e-29f596a179d4
```

But clicking it I get a 404

```
[Route("help")]
public class HelpController : Controller
{
 [HttpGet("privacy-policy")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> PrivacyPolicy(string id)
 {
   // stuff
 }
}
```

What have i done wrong.

Comment: Pretty sure you need id in the route: `[HttpGet("privacy-policy/{id}")]`

Comment: in addition to above comment: with your current configuration, the following request should work for you, where id is a query parameter, not part of the route:
`http://localhost:63110/help/privacy-policy?id=9b933739-15d0-4c60-a84e-29f596a179d4`

Comment: yes, thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to use `{id}` parameter in `HttpGet()`.

You can implement your action like following.

```
[HttpGet("privacy-policy/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PrivacyPolicy(string id)
{
   // stuff
}
```